# How to get reference for sibling childviews in a group expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onclicklistener, childviews

I am trying to implement a scenario in which user will selection one option among many in a group. See picture below:

[image]

In figure above, under group named **Sauce**, there are 3 options. User needs to check only 1 option among these. e.g. If user previously selected "Hot". After that he taps on "Mild" then check must disappear from "Hot" and appear on "Mild". I hope you got this point.

To achieve this approach, I need to have reference of either `a group's childviews` or `individual checks`, *so that I can toggle my checkmarks*. I really don't know what to do at this point... Please help me. Thanks..

**childlayout.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <ImageView
android:id="@+id/checkmark"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/childname"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:src="@drawable/checkmark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Child OnClick Listener**

```java
list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                     //how to get reference to other children here to toggle checkmark of current as well as previously tapped child's checkmark?  

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please, post layout xml snippet from `Sauce` to `Extra hot`

Comment: @ssantos i have already posted xml. text is just picked up from list for both group n child views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a hashmap to store references of all children when they were created in `getChildView`. In my custom adapter, I declared:

```
private HashMap<String, View> childviewReferences = new HashMap<String, View>();

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childStr = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

       LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);//context.getLayoutInflater();

    convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.childlayout, null);

     TextView textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childname);
                textview.setText(childStr);
    childviewReferences.put(Integer.toString(groupPosition) + Integer.toString(childPosition), convertView);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Child OnClick Listener**

```
list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

              @Override
              public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

CreatePizzaAdapter adapter = (CreatePizzaAdapter) parent.getExpandableListAdapter();

        View conv = adapter.getChildviewReferences().get(Integer.toString(groupPosition) + Integer.toString(childPosition));

                    //now you can find any view and child and do anything
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```